# DateTime column cannot be deserialized

Tags: java, json, hibernate, datetime, deserialization

I have a Java project with MySQL database. I need to fetch entries from database and this is where I get the following error. The column that cannot be deserialized is DateTime created. I use custom deserializer class.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.findActiveInternalNews(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at endpoints.v3.internalnews.InternalNewsController.getInternalNewsEntries(InternalNewsController.java:134) ~[classes/:na]
    at endpoints.v3.internalnews.InternalNewsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92417729.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at endpoints.v3.internalnews.InternalNewsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25d3882d.getInternalNewsEntries(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) [websocket-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at conf.filters.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:30) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at common.security.ApiAuthExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(ApiAuthExceptionFilter.java:38) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) [jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708) ~[jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626) ~[jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2854) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1747) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1673) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1489) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303230
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:936) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 155 common frames omitted
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "WhateverEntity")
@Table(name = "whatever_table_entry")
@Getter
@Setter
@Immutable
public class WhateverEntity{

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "priority")
  private String priority;

  @Column(name = "created")
  private DateTime created = new DateTime();

  @Column(name = "notification_sent")
  private Date notificationSent;

}
```

Here is the DTO class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Schema(name = "WhateverEntityDto.whateverentity")
public class WhateverEntityDto {

    @NotBlank
    private Long id;

    @Schema(example = "IMPORTANT")
    @NotBlank
    private String priority;

    @Schema
    @JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @NotBlank
    private DateTime created;

    @Schema
    private Date notificationSent;
     
    public WhateverEntityDto(WhateverEntity whateverEntity) {
        this.id = whateverEntity.getId();
        this.priority = whateverEntity.getPriority();
        this.created = whateverEntity.getCreated();
        this.notificationSent = whateverEntity.getNotificationSent();
    }

}
```

Here is the repository:

```
public interface WhateverEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<WhateverEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select we from WhateverEntity we")
    List<WhateverEntity> findActiveWhateverEntities(Long id, Date date);
}
```

and here controller's method where the error comes:

```
package com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.FormatConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.ReadableInstant;

public class DateTimeDeserializer extends JodaDateDeserializerBase<ReadableInstant> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DateTimeDeserializer(Class<?> cls, JacksonJodaDateFormat format) {
        super(cls, format);
    }

    public static <T extends ReadableInstant> JsonDeserializer<T> forType(Class<T> cls) {
        return new DateTimeDeserializer(cls, FormatConfig.DEFAULT_DATETIME_PARSER);
    }

    public JodaDateDeserializerBase<?> withFormat(JacksonJodaDateFormat format) {
        return new DateTimeDeserializer(this._valueClass, format);
    }

    public ReadableInstant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();
        if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
            DateTimeZone tz = this._format.isTimezoneExplicit() ? this._format.getTimeZone() : DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(ctxt.getTimeZone());
            return new DateTime(p.getLongValue(), tz);
        } else if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            String str = p.getText().trim();
            if (str.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                int ix = str.indexOf(91);
                if (ix > 0) {
                    int ix2 = str.lastIndexOf(93);
                    String tzId = ix2 < ix ? str.substring(ix + 1) : str.substring(ix + 1, ix2);

                    DateTimeZone tz;
                    try {
                        tz = DateTimeZone.forID(tzId);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException var10) {
                        ctxt.reportInputMismatch(this.handledType(), "Unknown DateTimeZone id '%s'", new Object[]{tzId});
                        tz = null;
                    }

                    str = str.substring(0, ix);
                    DateTime result = this._format.createParser(ctxt).withZone(tz).parseDateTime(str);
                    if (this._format.shouldAdjustToContextTimeZone(ctxt)) {
                        result = result.withZone(this._format.getTimeZone());
                    }

                    return result;
                } else {
                    return this._format.createParser(ctxt).parseDateTime(str);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return (ReadableInstant)this._handleNotNumberOrString(p, ctxt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have shown is `Jackson` deserializer - used to parse JSON into object. What fails in your case is `Hibernate` deserialization - value read from the database cannot be autoconverted to required class.

Comment: Like @Antoniossss said, this is a Hibernate/JPA error, not related to Jackson. What is thise `DateTime` type you are using for 'created' and where does it come from?

Comment: Is there a special reason for you to use Joda Time? Can't you use `java.time`?

Comment: Create variable as `private Date created` instead of `private DateTime created = new DateTime()`

Comment: Joda Time is already used in other DTOs in the project

Comment: @deHaar If I use java.time.ZonedTimeDate for example, I get null value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you persisted your created data in a serialized java object representation which is an issue already. IMO you should drop the usage of Joda Time and switch to Java 8 time types. With the [Hibernate integration for Java 8 time types](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8/5.1.14.Final/jar) the data will be save with the proper timestamp type on the database which will avoid the issue you are running into. For Jackson, there are also builtin serializers/deserializers that can handle these types.